# Javascript If Statement behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, ajax, if-statement, behavior

Strange problem with Javascript. What happens:

- User presses button, it passes an ASCII value to a script.
- The ASCII value is stored in a variable called "choice"
- The script then scrolls through an XML file and compares the first letter of each movie title to var choice.
- The point of the script is to display to the user all movies that start with the letter of their choice.

**The Problem:**

- All letters work fine except for S and P.

function go(choice) {

```
var nextChar = choice;
nextChar++; 

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "../xml/movielist.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: function (xml)
{
    var link = '<a href="';
    var linkMid = '">';
    var linkEnd = "</a>";
    var output = "";

    $(xml).find('movie').each(function ()                                                 //For each <Movie> tag, retrieve the following:
    {                                          
        var title = $(this).find('title').text()                                          //Retreive Movie's Title

        if ((title.substring(0, 5) == "The " + String.fromCharCode(choice)) || (title.substring(0, 1) == String.fromCharCode(choice)) || (title.substring(0, 3) == "A " + String.fromCharCode(choice)))
        {
            /*Deleted lines here to save space and they also don't apply to the problem at hand*/
            output = output + "<tr>" + rowOut + "</td>";

        }
        if (title.substring(0, 1) == String.fromCharCode(nextChar))
        {
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = output;
            return false;
        }               

    })
}
```

})
};

Sample XML code. These are the first two movies that begin with the letter S.

```
  <movie>
    <title>Salt</title>
    <link>films/salt.aspx</link>
    <runtime>1h 34m</runtime>
  </movie>
  <movie>
    <title>See No Evil</title>
    <link>films/seenoevil.aspx</link>
    <runtime>1h 24m</runtime>
  </movie>
```

Let me just reiterate that this script works great and outputs the results to the screen for every single letter besides S, P and Z (although I know why Z doesn't work, I haven't written the code yet). I have no idea why S and P would behave differently. Through some debugging, I've deduced that the If statement is never even entered when the user selects S or P, which means the conditions in the If statement aren't being met even though the variable "choice" equals 80 or 83 (P or S respectively) throughout the entire exercise.

I'm sure it's something silly, but I can't really seem to wrap my head around it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to take what you posted and distill it into something a bit more concentrated. Imagine you're writing an e-mail to your coworker. It is very hard for us to read paragraphs and paragraphs and figure out what you want. Give a couple of sentences of background, explain what you need to, then state your question explicitly. That way, it'll be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Are you sure the title doesn't have leading spaces? Also have you tried testing it only for if (title.substring(0, 1) == String.fromCharCode(choice)) when the choice is "S"?

Comment: @JeromeAnthony Yes, I have tried just that one condition and none of the titles in the XML file have a space in front of them.

Comment: @TylerDean can you share a sample section from the xml file which fails for the scenario?

Comment: Sure I'll put it in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. The problem was a mixture of illogical conditions in the If statements and faulty design. The program would return false when the loop encountered a movie that started with the next letter. So if the user chose the letter "S", the script would iterate through the XML file and find all of the movies that started with the letter S. In this case, the loop would then exit when it hit a movie that started with the letter "T".

```
    if (title.substring(0, 1) == String.fromCharCode(nextChar))
    {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = output;
        return false;
    }
```

This bit of code was responsible for this. The problem was that when the user chose "S", the loop would run until it hit a movie that started with the letter "T". There were many movies that began with "The" like for example, "The Internship". This would cause the loop to exit prematurely.

To fix this I changed the break condition to:

```
        if (choice == 83)                                                                 //If the user chose the letter "S", use this condition to break the loop instead. Special Case!
        {
            if ((title.substring(0, 5) == "The T"))
            {
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = output;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if ((String.fromCharCode(nextChar) == title.substring(0, 1)) && (title.substring(0, 5) != "The " + String.fromCharCode(choice))) //Otherwise exit normally
        {
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = output;
            return false;
        }
```

This ensured that the loop would exit normally in ALL cases including S. If the user chose the letter S, it would exit if and Only if the next movie began with the letter T or "The T" but did not begin with "The S".

The new and completely functional code looks something similar to this (I edited out unnecessary lines for neatness and saving space):

```
    $(xml).find('movie').each(function ()                                                 //For each <Movie> tag, retrieve the following:
    {                                          
        var title = $(this).find('title').text()                                          //Retreive Movie's Title

        if ((choice == title.substring(0, 1).charCodeAt()) || (title.substring(0, 3) == "A " + String.fromCharCode(choice)))          //If the first letter of the movie starts with the user's chosen letter OR If the movie starts with A_ and the user's chosen letter
        {
            //Do stuff here
        }

        if ((title.substring(0, 5) == "The " + String.fromCharCode(choice)))              //If the movie starts with The_ and the user's chosen letter
        {
            //Otherwise, do stuff here
        }

        if (choice == 83)                                                                 //If the user chose the letter "S", use this condition to break the loop instead. Special Case!
        {
            if ((title.substring(0, 5) == "The T"))
            {
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = output;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if ((String.fromCharCode(nextChar) == title.substring(0, 1)) && (title.substring(0, 5) != "The " + String.fromCharCode(choice))) //Otherwise exit normally
        {
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = output;
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `choice == title.substring(0, 1).charCodeAt()`

Comment: The same problem still exists. All letters work besides "S" and "P"